# iPhone won't let me swipe down on my parallax site. Toio much Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone, skrollr

Testing this current project I'm working on (http://hp1.icorp.net/datatv/mwc/index.html) and it's fine on desktop but on my iPhone 6, the page loads but I can't seem to swipe downwards for more content. I'm wondering if it's because I'm using the Skrollr JS scripts to add parallax and other animated effects to the site.

The good news is that the navigation does work, so it does point down to the right portions of my one pager, but because there are animation opacity effects added, I can't see my content without swiping.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found out to make it work on iOS, you have to add another div or section tag with the class of 'skrollr-body' to make that work. Sneaky!